# Testing elasticsearch with nock in nodejs

Tags: elasticsearch, nock

1. Hit the API in real, but only nock the service layer (i.e) the
   elastic search layer request to database,say-(localhost:9200//).How
   can I hit the API but only intercept the elasticsearch request to
   database?
2. I have several layers like API layer and service layer and the
   database layer in my project. So I used nock to mock the requests in
       the API layer. But I mainly want to mock the data present in
       elasticsearch service layer to database layer. In other words, the
       API layer should work with real hits, but the elasticsearch layer
       should only be nocked.
   The expected result is only mocking elasticsearch layer not the entire API request and response.
   This is the snippet I used for mocking the request and response in API layer.

   ```
   it('should return a user', () => {    
         nock('https://randomuser.me')
           .get('/myapi/')
           .reply(200, {
             results: [{ name: 'Dovahkiin' }],
           });
         return query
           .getQueryRequest()
           .then(res => res.results[0].name)
           .then(res => expect(res).toEqual('Dovahkiin'));
       });
   ```

Comment: What happens when you try 'nock("https://localhost:9200")...'? It should work.

Comment: SO is converting that origin and removing the protocol when it renders, but you do need to include the 'http://' bit

Comment: @MattR.Wilson Thanks for the response, but I want API hits to be real and only the elasticsearch requests should be mocked. Can this all be encapsulated in nock? If so, how can I achieve it?

Answer (score 2):

The order in which you import Nock can play an important role. For example, I had the following in a suite of my own:

```
const API = require('api')
const Nock = require('nock')
```

My API module required Elasticsearch, and for the life of me, I couldn't get Nock to intercept the requests the elasticsearch-js module was making. However, ***after simply reversing the import order***, my test worked as expected, since Nock needs a chance to override `http.request` and `http.ClientRequest` before libraries that consume them are brought up.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the issue is around attempting to nock localhost, it's blocking and/or mocking other localhost requests that aren't headed for port 9200.

If I have that right, you can use the [allowUnmocked](https://github.com/nock/nock#allow-unmocked-requests-on-a-mocked-hostname) option when creating a nock scope around localhost.

From the docs:

> If you need some request on the same host name to be mocked and some
>   others to really go through the HTTP stack, you can use the
>   allowUnmocked option

```
  nock('https://localhost:9200', { allowUnmocked: true })
    .get('/somepath')
    .reply(200, {
      results: [{ name: 'Dovahkiin' }],
    });
```

Comment: Surprisingly, it didn't work for me. I want all other calls except the elasticsearch call to be real requests to the server. But I used chai-http to integrate with nock but in vain. Is there any other way by which I can integrate real server requests with nock?

Comment: @Dovabornn can you edit your question to provide more of an example around how your test is setup and run. And are you getting any errors? Also you make reference the "API layer" a lot, are you referring to the server that receives requests in your app or a third party API that your app is communicating with?